unknown memory leak in Qt6 C++
I installed deleaker and decided to test it on a small code, as a result, I got 1 error about a memory leak, which, as for me, should not be and I do not understand where it comes from

qtenvironmentvariables.cpp, line 117 (C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtbase\src\corelib\global\qtenvironmentvariables.cpp)   0x000002a22a643c90  1   Heap memory Qt6Core.dll C:\Qt\6.7.0\mingw_64\bin\Qt6Core.dll    4046    18412   29.04.2024 01:16:15.3330000 212 6108

#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow b;
    b.show();

    return a.exec();
}


qtenvironmentvariables.cpp, line 117 It looks like its nothing to worry about. Looks like a 1 time  block of memory allocated for the OS environment variables. Even if the Qt internal code did not free this block it would go away when the program ends.
